# Restkit creating NULL core data objects

Tags: restkit

I am building an app with Restkit to sync up with a web service.  The first loadObjectsAtResourcePath call works properly, but then each additional call creates a new a row of all NULLs.  A typical JSON response is:

```
[{"item":{"created_at":"2012-04-19T19:42:44Z","id":4,"json_event_id":null,"name":"Biz Cards","theme_id":null,"updated_at":"2012-04-19T19:42:44Z","url":"","user_id":3}},{"item":{"created_at":"2012-04-20T19:37:33Z","id":5,"json_event_id":null,"name":"Hummus","theme_id":null,"updated_at":"2012-04-20T19:37:33Z","url":"","user_id":3}}]
```

The first time I call loadObjectsAtResourcePath, I correctly get the two objects created in core data.  The next time I call it, I get an additional row in Sqlite with a new PK and all NULLs.  Each subsequent call creates a new NULL row with the PK incremented.

Here is my mapping:

```
RKManagedObjectMapping *itemsMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Items class] inManagedObjectStore:objectManager.objectStore];
itemsMapping.primaryKeyAttribute = @"itemID";
[itemsMapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:@"created_at", @"createdAt",
 @"id", @"itemID",
 @"json_event_id", @"json_event_id",
 @"name", @"name",
 @"theme_id", @"theme_id",
 @"updated_at", @"updatedAt",
 @"url", @"url",
 @"user_id", @"user_id", nil];
```

And here is my call to the web service:

```
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
[objectManager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/items" delegate:self];
```

Any help on why this is creating those additional rows would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where do you associate the mapping with a keypath or with a resourceurlpattern?